# React Native: Keyboard dismisses on first load

Tags: react-native

```html
export default function HomeScreen() {
    const [length, setLength] = useState("");
    const [breadth, setBreadth] = useState("");
    const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState("0");

    const handleLengthChange = (text) => {
        setLength(text);
    };
    const handleBreadthChange = (text) => {
        setBreadth(text);
    };


    return (
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                <Card>
                    <Dimension
                        length={length}
                        breadth={breadth}
                        handleLengthChange={handleLengthChange}
                        handleBreadthChange={handleBreadthChange}
                    />
                    <QualitySelector />
                    <Rate />
                </Card>
                <Card>
                    <Result totalCost={totalCost} />
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>

            <View style={globalStyles.absoluteButton}>
                <FlatButton />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

```html
export default function Dimension({
length, 
breadth, 
handleLengthChange, 
handleBreadthChange
}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
            <Text style={globalStyles.sectionTitle}>Dimension</Text>
            <View style={styles.sectionOption}>
                <Text style={globalStyles.inputTitle}>Length</Text>
                <TextInput
                    value={length}
                    style={{ ...globalStyles.inputField, ...styles.inputField }}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChangeText={(text) => handleLengthChange(text)}
                />
                <Text style={styles.inputUnit}>meter</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionOption}>
                <Text style={globalStyles.inputTitle}>Breadth</Text>
                <TextInput
                    value={breadth}
                    style={{ ...globalStyles.inputField, ...styles.inputField }}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChangeText={(text) => handleBreadthChange(text)}
                />
                <Text style={styles.inputUnit}>meter</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I am building a project with expo. My project happens to have a form field but I haven't used any library for handling forms. Whenever I try tapping on one of the TextInput fields, the keyboard appears and disappears right away. But after that if I tap again in input field, keyboard remains on screen. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is. I've searched a lot on google but there isn't a single result which discusses the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: @D10S I've update the post with code.

Comment: I can't see were yoe receive the props in Dimension but assuming you handle that - try to remove the "value={...}" from the TextInput components. how does it behave now?

Comment: Actually I was trying something and removed the props and forgot to revert back. Now I've updated it. Removing "value={...}" also doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem was specific to my device only. Might be some kind of bug in expo. If anyone has the same problem try running your app on multiple devices. If the problem still persists, eject your project and run it using bare react-native.